# How do I get the full list list sent via telegram when web scrapping

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, telegram

I have managed to get the text I want but I can't seem to send the entire list to a telegram message. I only manage to send the first line.

```
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("")

Source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(Source, "html.parser")

for cars in soup.findAll(class_="car-title"):
    print(cars.text)

driver.close()


def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = ''
    bot_chatID = ''
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

test = telegram_bot_sendtext(cars.text)
```

The print function gives me this

```
AUDI E-TRON 
MERCEDES-BENZ EQC 
TESLA MODEL 3 
NISSAN LEAF 
MERCEDES-BENZ EQV 
AUDI E-TRON
```

At some point I would like to add a function to check for updates and if there any changes then send a push message to telegram. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: sorry, it's a little bit unclear what you are asking. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Your sending one line, cause you do not store the results anywhere and only the last result from iterating is in memory.

#### How to fix?

Asuming you want to send text as in the question, you should store results in variable - Iterate over resultset, extract text and `join()` results by newline character:

```
cars = '\n'.join([cars.text for cars in soup.find_all(class_="car-title")])
```

#### Example

```
...
cars = '\n'.join([cars.text for cars in soup.find_all(class_="car-title")])

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = ''
    bot_chatID = ''
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

test = telegram_bot_sendtext(cars)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is now not sending anything to the telegram chat. There are no errors.